# Problem with Android Game made using Unity Engine

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, google-play-services

I developed an Android game called "ZigZag Bird" which was developed using Unity Engine.

My game has 3 different game modes. Vertical, Horizontal and Flappy (Flappy Bird classic), The game uses Goggle's Play Games Service to record the score of each of the Game Modes.

I tested it for several days and everything looked OK, so I released it on the Play Store.

However, some people have reported that the leaderboard is not registering score in any mode. And another person reported that it was not registering scores in a certain game mode.

Honestly, I'm resorting to Stack Overflow a little desperate because I have no idea what could be happening because on all the devices I've tested everything works fine.

Has anyone faced this problem? Feel free to search and install the game and see if the issue occurs on your device.

I decided not to take the game offline even with this problem. Help me please. I am desperate. =/

Comment: much as we can comiserate with your story, you have given us nothing to work with with.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the exact problem. It looks more like marketing than a call for help.

Comment: It wasn't marketing. It was a real problem. Thanks for the interest anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for those interested in the problem. It wasn't marketing. It was a real problem. I found out in another Forum that it was the SHA1 key that in production must be a key that Google generates in the Play Console and not the keystore that I was using when testing the APP. It worked on some devices because I had sent the APK to some friends to test.

The forum where I found the solution:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2045

Thank you very much.